# Is there a shortcut to insert the unix time stamp into the code in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Inserting the unix time stamps is common technique to create ids within the code. I guess this can be done by Live Templates. Other solutions are also welcome.

*Background:*

As an official of IntelliJ was asking, why I call it common. I know it from TYPO3 to give unique ids to exceptions. They point to a wiki page, where the community can give specific solutions.

https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1313855175

Many developers use PHPStorm.

In my current Android project I give unique ids while wiring up a graph of hundreds of objects. The relations are hardcoded in a setup file.

Comment: I'm not sure why you refer to it as a common technique; I've never seen it used, described, or requested by users of IntelliJ IDEA. There is no built-in feature to do this (not even through live templates), but you can write a simple plugin to do it for you.

Comment: Yes, a plugin may be a solution in case there is no smarter one. 

It is a technique I have seen in successful open source projects, to create unique ids for exceptions. That's reason to call it common.

Comment: By the way  IntelliJ IDEA is really a great IDE, for me especially due to it's strong support for vim mode. Kudos!